# Passing data from an Activity to its View

Tags: android

This is a newbie question. What is the best way to pass an object from an Activity to its View? I know the View has access to its context. Are Intents still the way to go? Or is there something else?

EDIT: Did not know the details about the data mattered :)

The data is user information obtained from a server in the Activity stored in an object. It contains userid, name and other details (mix of longs and strings).

The idea is to use/show the data in the view and possibly modify some of the fields and pass it back to the Activity which will send it to the server. Also I create and launch the View after I have the User information object with me. So after the View is launched it has to somehow get the object when it wants to use it.

P

Comment: What kind of data? And when you say passing it to its View what exactly do you mean? Making a TextView display some data as text or something similar? Or have you subclassed view in such a way that it needs some kind of data? give us a little bit more info about what it is you are trying to accomplish and it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more details of what exactly you are trying to do? How is the View related to the Activity?

Comment: Thanks for viewing the question. Edited it to add more info.

Comment: @Aedon - What is a bundle? And how do I pass it to the View from the Activity?

Comment: A bundle is the basic form of data transfer for android. Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Comment: You use it when ever you create an activity. It stores the states of activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setTag: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: This is somthing specific to the View. Can I set these tags from the Activity before launching the view? Because that is what I need, I have the User object in my hand and then I create and launch the View. The View should get the User object when its ready to use it.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a custom View object that you are creating using a custom constructor: you should probably just pass your User object into the constructor. If its being inflated from XML, then you can set the tag in `onCreate` immediately after you inflate the View, or you can grab the View instance using `findViewById`, cast it to the right class and then call a method that takes the User object. If you do this in `onCreate` it will all happen before the View is displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly mean with passing data form an activity to a view as a view is normally part of an activity.

So I would suggest you start an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method of your activity which downloads the data from the server. When the AsyncTask finished you pass the data pack to a method of you activity which takes the data and fills the corresponding view elements. To get a reference to the views like [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and so on you can use the method [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29).

When the finished editing the data he must press a [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) which triggers an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) that fetches the edited data from the views and starts another AsyncTask to upload the data back to the server.